# How to use high and low naming with negation on Eagle

Tags: eaglecad

I noticed it's possible to give present a negation value by calling a variable the following:

!A

However I'm trying to imitate an existing part where A has the header line, and B doesn't
and it only works if I go at it backwards:
[image]

While this is what what I want
[image]

B/!A as oppose to !A/B
[image]

There might be some sort of syntax I'm unaware of.
I've already tried !{A}/B !(A)/B and !A_/B.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just like the Eagle documentation says, a second "!" in a name ends the inversion bar above the text.  For example, if you want "not A, B", the name for that net in Eagle would be "!A!/B".  The first "!" starts the inversion bar and the second ends it.

For example, here is the result of "!RESET!/RUN":

[image]